# SQL Query with 2 OR statments and 1 AND statement

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am attempting to run a SQL query like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from users where new_mail = 0 OR new_events = 0 and emailed = 1") or die(mysql_error());
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    mysql_query("update users set emailed = 0 where username='{$r['username']}'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

However it seem to ignore the OR statements and only follows the and statement. So it goes ahead and sets emailed to 0 even if they still have new_mail or new_event. Any clue why?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the structure of your table and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please stop using mysql_* functions and switch to PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: try putting new_email or new_events in () ie (new_email=0 or new_events=0)

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MySQL, the `AND` operator has a higher [precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operator-precedence.html) over the `OR` operator.

To get the logic you desire, try grouping the parameters in the way you want them to be evaluated:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from users where (new_mail = 0 OR new_events = 0) and emailed = 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from users where (new_mail = 0 OR new_events = 0) and emailed = 1") or die(mysql_error());
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    mysql_query("update users set emailed = 0 where username='{$r['username']}'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

You'll probably need to add parenthesis to the where clause

Answer (score 2):

Put parenthesis around the OR clauses, segmenting it from the AND clause.

Answer (score 2):

According to MYSQL order of operations, `AND` statements in a `WHERE` clause are evaluated before `OR` statements unless grouped. I'm assuming what you want to do is for the query to return true if either new_mail or new_events is 0 and emailed is set to 0.

If so you need to group your OR statement like so:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE (new_mail = 0 OR new_events = 0) AND emailed = 1"
```

You can also simplify this to one query if you are not doing anything else in that loop by applying the `WHERE` clause directly to the `UPDATE` query like so.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET emailed = 0 WHERE (new_mail = 0 OR new_events = 0) AND emailed = 1"
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())
```